# How do I replace values in an entire dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

So I need to replace all values in my dataframe named 'x', that are greater than 140 and less than 35, with 0. I have 600 columns all named 1-600. I've tried the method below but I can't figure out how I can apply this to the entire dataset.

```
x=x.mask(x['1']>140,0)
```

When I try doing this

```
x=x.mask(x>140,0)
```

This is the error message:

**TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**

Can someone please help me out, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert your dataframe all columns to `int` type using `df = df.astype(int)`

You could try numpy `astype`:

```
a = df.values
#convert datatype to int
a = a.astype(int)
pd.DataFrame(np.where(( a > 140) | (a < 35) , 0, a))
```

Also, you can use `mask` as follows:

```
df.mask((df > 140) | (df < 35) , 0)
```

Comment: Thank you but it still showed the same error, TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @MaryA, your data frame contains only integer, then you should convert them to `int` type as follows `df = df.astype(int)` before performing the operation. The error clearly says that column doesn't have `int` type. Or you should choose only integer columns.

Comment: @MaryA, No issue thanks. Mark as correct answer then it could help others to see the solution at least.

Answer (score 2):

If you write `x`, it means the dataframe, in order to address the content of it, you have to write `x[:]`:

```python
x = x.mask(x[:]>140, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you but it still showed the same error, TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I changed the dataframe to numeric and it worked, thank you.